How to check if the value of a field is updated after submitting form?
I have an editable form to update user profile. After clicking submit button, I want to check if the value in the said field changed according to the new value I input. For example, this is one of the field
<div class="mb-3 row">
   <label class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Email</label>
   <div class="col-sm-4">
       <input required="" type="text" disabled class="form-control">
   </div>
</div>

The form is a pop up and after submitting, the page reload showing disabled field. How can I check if the value has changed using Puppeteer?
I already tried using text locator but it's not dynamic enough, I need it to be dynamic depends on my input

Did you try writing any Puppeteer code? If the actual site involves a page reload, please share that as part of your [mcve] so we can understand exactly what you're testing. Thanks.
